# Unexpected Node.js program flow

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js and working through the API.  In the stream module docs I came across this example of the "unpipe event" (actually a fusion of two examples in the docs).

```
const fs = require("fs);

const writable = fs.createWriteStream("write.txt");
const readable = fs.createReadStream("read.txt");

readable.pipe(writable);

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Stop writing to file.txt");
    readable.unpipe(writable);
    console.log("Manually close the file stream");
    writable.end();    
}, 0);

writable.on("unpipe", function(src){
    console.log("Something has stopped piping into the writer");
});
```

I can't understand the following console.log order:

```
"Stop writing to file.txt"
"Something has stopped piping into the writer"
"Manually close the file stream"
```

Given the setTimeout callback is running - which is the first phase of the event loop as I understand - how on earth does the callback for the "unpipe" event start to run before the setTimeout callback has finished.

Originally I had the setTimeout firing after a time above zero seconds, however I was finding that the unpipe call back was always called first.  I reasoned that my computer was reading the file always first before the setTimeout was ready.  (Although I can't see any mention in the docs about the completion of the write to the file eliciting the "unpipe" event, but this makes sense I suppose).  However I can't for the life of me reason how the above program flow is occurring.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Event handler callbacks emit synchronously

Comment: Ah, thanks.  And I've just checked client side JS in the browser with the event emitter and what you said is true in that example also.  So "event handlers" aren't dealt with by the event loop then, correct?

Comment: To be extremely precise - they are dealt with by the event loop, but in synchronous manner which means in the same turn of the event loop as the `setTimeout` handler in your snippet :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll be covering the "Events" module next I think lol.  Cheers everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by the [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_asynchronous_vs_synchronous):

> The `EventEmitter` calls all listeners synchronously in the order in which they were registered.

That is, when `.emit` is called, it synchronously runs through all listeners for the emitted event and calls them.

Note that if necessary you can wrap your callback code in `process.nextTick` to ensure that it will always run asynchronously, but in your case it's likely that's unnecessary.

Also the source of the call to `.emit` (the emission of the event) will often be asynchronous.